# Sidekiq Worker Pattern

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have Sidekiq up and running on a RoR application. All works great and jobs are queued up.

I have seen a lot of patterns as far as queuing up jobs but am curios about this pattern which I see in production and works well. It is idempotent, can work with multiple Sidekiq workers and the `generate` method does the magic....

Any opinions on whether this is a good pattern to use...?

class MailerDeamon
      include Sidekiq::Worker

```
  def perform(id)
    # idempotent 
    email = Email::Message.find_by(id: id)
    return unless email
    return unless email.sent? # or something that marks it has been sent

    email.begin_transmission!
  end

  def self.generate
    Email::Message.triggered(60).ids.each do |id|
      perform_async(id)
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good pattern to use.  Something like this:

```
email.begin_transmission!
email.mark_as_sent!
```

The only problem that might occur is if your database dies after the email is sent but before it can be marked as sent.  In that case, you can get a double delivery but that should be exceedingly rare.